# Case no Where usando SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

Tenho o seguinte código que lista determinados acordos comerciais. Tem a opção Sim ou Não.

```
   DECLARE @Opcao VARCHAR(7)

   SET @Opcao = 'S'

   SELECT * FROM 
   BLA BLA BLA

WHERE
    ((('{Opcao}' = 'S') AND NFDataEmis BETWEEN lme.LogMovEstqDataHora AND ppme.ParcPagMovEstqDataVenc) or ('{Opcao}' = 'N'))
    AND ec.CategCodEstr like '{Categoria}' + '%'
    AND crd.ClasseRecDespCodEstr like '{Acordo}' +'%'
    AND me.MovEstqDataMovimento BETWEEN @Data_inicial AND @Data_final
```

O que ocorre é que ele me traz todas as opções que estiverem listadas o S e o N. Eu queria fazer um CASE para trazer as opções que não estejam em S e N. Como que eu poderia fazer isso?

USO SQL SERVER

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, mas `Opcao NOT IN ('S', 'N')` ou `'{Opcao}' <> 'S'` não resolve?

Comment: É o seguinte Se a variável @Opcao for vazia, ele não pode executar o ((('{Opcao}' = 'S') AND NFDataEmis....Se for S ou N ele executa. Tentei com CASE mas não deu certo. Como que seria com IN?

Comment: aah sim, entendi, Opcao é uma coluna de alguma tabela?

Comment: Não Opcao é uma variável que vai listar os registros pela Data. Se for S ele lista conforme uma categoria se N por outra. Mas eu quero listar todas elas. Dai se for por todas ele não executa essa linha:  ((('{Opcao}' = 'S') AND NFDataEmis BETWEEN lme.LogMovEstqDataHora AND ppme.ParcPagMovEstqDataVenc) or ('{Opcao}' = 'N'))

Comment: Desculpa.. não sei se lerdeza.. mas ainda não me ficou claro, pelo que parece as variáveis em `{}` vem de algum código. mas achei essa [resposta no SO ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785288/6200920) que talvez possa te ajudar

Comment: Realmente, pela explicação está um pouco confuso. Mas penso que a solução final para a nossa compreensão exacta pode não ser a questão neste momento. Tente dar uma olhada nas respostas e caso não sirvam, tente explicar o porquê delas não funcionarem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Se a variável @Opcao for vazia, ele não pode executar o ((('{Opcao}' = 'S') AND NFDataEmis....Se for S ou N ele executa* (...)
>   *Opcao é uma variável que vai listar os registros pela Data. Se for S ele lista conforme uma categoria se N por outra. Mas eu quero listar todas elas. Dai se for por todas ele não executa essa linha:*
>   `((('{Opcao}' = 'S') AND NFDataEmis BETWEEN lme.LogMovEstqDataHora AND
>   ppme.ParcPagMovEstqDataVenc) or ('{Opcao}' = 'N'))`

A descrição do problema me parece não muito clara, afora a mistura de `{Opcao}` e `@Opcao` no mesmo código. Considerando-se a descrição do problema e os comentários posteriores do autor do tópico, eis esboço do código.

```
-- código #1
SELECT ...
  from ...
  where (@Opção is NULL 
         or (@Opção = 'S' 
             and NFDataEmis between lme.LogMovEstqDataHora and ppme.ParcPagMovEstqDataVenc)
         or @Opção = 'N')
        and ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Inclua a opção no **WHERE**

```
WHERE
        (IsNull(@opcao,'') In ('S') And NFDataEmis Between lme.LogMovEstqDataHora And ppme.ParcPagMovEstqDataVenc)
        Or
        (IsNull(@opcao,'') In ('N') And ec.CategCodEstr Like '{Categoria}' + '%' AND crd.ClasseRecDespCodEstr like '{Acordo}' +'%')
```